# what is role of libpng exactly?

Tags: libpng

I got security warning to my app from android market.

Google said my app should upgrade libpng version.

I use opencv in the app, and It seems like openCV use libpng library.

But I dont know how libpng library works.

Because I couldnt find libpng library in my project.

Is libpng library installed in OS (or OS`s common lib folder), and all applications refer to the library together ?

And libpng library is official library for viewing .png file ?
(it means libpng is necessary for viewing png files in any OS system like iOS, MacOS, Windows, Unix and etc..)

My understanding is OK ? or Much wrong ?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, libpng is the library for processing PNG files.  The warning is due to a security problem that was fixed in libpng in December 2015 and in OpenCV sometime thereafter.  Google allowed six months for people to rebuild their apps with the current version of OpenCV and libpng, then started issuing the warning you're seeing.  The same thing happens with apps using COCOS2DX.  libpng depends upon zlib, so you should upgrade zlib as well if it isn't current.

Comment: It means that libpng is already included in opencv, and opencv does not use default libpng in OS`s default common linpng library.. opencv use thier own libpng in its own project.   right ? then upgrade opencv version will solve the problem ?

Comment: I realize you are manager of libpng : ) do you think  OpenCV 3.1 is safe for libpng vulnerability? then I will upgrade to OpenCV 3.1

Comment: I don't know the exact status of OpenCV, but there are several other questions about this issue, tagged "libpng".  I believe the current version is OK.

Comment: I see. I will check it out : )